# JGroups opens two ports even though port_range is 0

Tags: jgroups

When using JGroups with TCP somehow it always opens two ports, which a visible over netstat -a -b. The first one is the configured bind port, e.g. 55600. This port also appears in GMS output. But there is also another one which is always opened, its number is always (?) bindPort +3, e.g. 55603. Any ideas what this port is needed for? Setting port_range to 0 has no effects. Diagnostics is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out myself by now: FD_SOCK protocol which you might have or not depending on your protocol stack. Its description is quite clear:

Failure detection protocol based on sockets. Failure detection is ring-based. Each member creates a server socket and announces its address together with the server socket's address in a multicast.

Comment: So how did you solve the problem? I have the same problem where 10 ports are exposed. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/72533075/12501050

Comment: By removing FD_SOCK from the protocol stack.